# Starting Windows service with OpenCover throws System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException

Tags: service, timeout, timeoutexception, opencover

I'm using OpenCover to start and cover a Windows service. I didn't write the service, but I've spoken to the developers and they said that on a good system, it can take up to 45 seconds for the service to complete all of its startup tasks. I'm able to start this service just fine through the Services menu, but when I attempt to start the service with OpenCover running, I get the `System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException` message about 30 seconds after the "Service is starting" message appears.

So, my question is, can I increase the timeout length for OpenCover, so that this service has enough time to start? I've looked through OpenCover's documentation, Googled for a while, and come up with nothing. If it's not currently possible, let me know so that I can put in a feature request on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option currently available you'll need to raise it as an issue